# Safely calling a stored procedure in sqlalchemy ona postgresdb

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, psycopg2, postgresql-14

I am trying to find a way to call stored proc with parameters `-sp` using `sqlAlchmey`. I found lots of answers non that solved my specific problem. As far as I understand we can always pass parameters to the `sqlAlchemy` text by first formatting the string using python . But from what I  have read, that is unsafe due to `sqlinjection` attacks . But I am unable to find a reliable way to pas parameters with out exposing it via text.
Can some one advice me what to do or where to look for any particular module I overlooked. Or perhaps my understanding is wrong or not enough. I am not sure where to look. Any advice is helpful. Thank you.

One way I tried is like this, which I think is unsafe?

```
Var1= 'CALL SP('%s');'%somevalfrom somwhere
Var2=sqlalchem.text(var1)
engine execute(var2)
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: There is not much of a code its that solution itself im looking for .     So  im establishing connection to a  postgress db using  sqlalchemy and psycopg2  on python . And i want to have python call stored procedures .I can just pass the sql commands for non parameter Stored procs .But for the ones which require params i am trying to find a good way or the right way  to pass the parameters to stored proc securely .More like rules or inbuilt functions that allows it . i am using alchmey im using conn.execute and pass txt query .ithinkicannot use cursor since its not supported on create _engine?